# Why could the point of origin not be discovered through a brute-force search?

Tags: stargate, symbols

An important part of the early plot of the original *Stargate* film is finding the "seventh symbol" - the "point of origin" that allows them to dial Abydos. The Air Force apparently already had recovered the first six, but couldn't make it work without calling in Dr. Jackson to find the seventh.

Why couldn't the seventh symbol have been discovered through brute force? There are only 39 symbols on the gate, and "failed" dials have been shown to be non-dangerous according to SG1 (dialing a "wrong number" doesn't make the gate explode or summon Cthulhu, it just doesn't open a wormhole). Even if they chose to try only one candidate seventh symbol per day, they would have found it in a few weeks - why even bother with tracking down an Egyptologist?

I know that the out-of-universe answer is plot - that Dr. Jackson would never have been recruited if they could have just tried addresses until they succeeded. I'm asking about the *in-universe* reason. Was this ever addressed in any *Stargate* material? Was there a fear that the gate would blow up if the wrong seventh symbol was used? Was the energy requirement to dial the gate with the primitive equipment they had at the beginning so enormous that getting it right on the first try was a major budgetary goal?

Comment: They simply didn't realise that a seventh symbol was required because they didn't recognise the symbols as constellations (and hence as a system of plotting movement, and hence requiring a point of origin).

Comment: @Valorum Your dupe target is a few hours newer than this question :-) Not that that means it shouldn't be closed, but why did you answer the newer one instead of the older one?

Comment: @Randal'Thor - This one was deleted when I went to answer it.